Issue with Console Input Delay in Java Program
I'm working on a Java program that takes user input from the console using BufferedReader for a command-line interface. However, I'm experiencing a noticeable delay when printing the prompt ">" after the user presses Enter.
take the windows CMD or Cisco CLI for example, when you press enter it immediately moves to the next line. However, in this program it instantly moves to the next line BUT it takes a fairly considerable delay before it reprints the "> ".
Say if i press enter 6 times in quick concession:
What I want:

    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 

What I get: 
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
    > > > > > > 

I'm in no means an experienced programmer, this is for a second-year solo uni project. But I would love to find out how this could be optimized, or if its simply my IDE hahaha, we have to use netbeans.
Heres the relevant snippet that reprints "> ":
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer tp = new TaskPrinter();
        TaskCreator tc = new TaskCreator();
        TaskRemover tr = new TaskRemover();
        TaskUpdater tu = new TaskUpdater();
        TaskManagerController tmc = new TaskManagerController(tp, tc, tr, tu);

        try ( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Enter '?' to see list of commands.");
            System.out.println("Enter 'exit' to end session.");
            System.out.println("Max Name Length: " + tc.getNameLength());
            String userInput;
            do {

**//"> " IS REPRINTED HERE**
                System.out.print("> ");
                System.out.flush();
                userInput = reader.readLine().trim();

**// THIS METHOD IS RUN BEFORE GOING BACK TO PRINT "> " AGAIN.
// NOT SURE IF THIS IS THE PROBLEM OR NOT :)**
                tmc.processCommand(userInput);
            } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

If its relevant here is the processCommand method:
public void processCommand(String userInput) {
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
        switch (userInput) {
            //check for commands
            case "":
                break;
            case "display all":
            case "display a":
            case "display al":
                tp.printDisplayAll();
                break;
            case "display task":
            case "display t":
            case "display ta":
            case "display tas":
                tp.printDisplay();
                break;
            case "remove all":
            case "remove a":
            case "remove al":
                tr.removeAll();
                break;
            case "remove task":
            case "remove t":
            case "remove ta":
            case "remove tas":
                tr.removeTask();
                break;
            case "create":
            case "c":
            case "cr":
            case "cre":
            case "crea":
            case "creat":
                tc.createTask();
                break;
            case "?":
                tp.printCommands();
                break;
            case "update":
            case "u":
            case "up":
            case "upd":
            case "upda":
            case "updat":
                tu.updateCompleteStatus();
                break;
            case "remove":
            case "r":
            case "re":
            case "rem":
            case "remo":
            case "remov":
                System.out.println("unambiguous command");
                break;
            case "display":
            case "d":
            case "di":
            case "dis":
            case "disp":
            case "displ":
            case "displa":
                System.out.println("unambiguous command");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unrecognized Command.");
                break;
        }
    }

It was originally scanning input with the Scanner class, I was hoping the buffered reader would make a difference but unfortunately not. the switch statement in the processCommand method was also originally an if else ladder. I changed it to a switch statement as I always thought these were quicker, but the delay is unchanged.
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated and I'm very open to trying any ideas suggested. Thanks everyone.
I've noticed that the problem is being fixed by using System.out.println("> ");
instead of
System.out.print("> ");
However I want to use System.out.print() as I do not want the extra newline
as another note, If I use Eclipse there is no delay in printing. As Eclipse is forbidden by our lecturer, it looks like I may be doomed with using Netbeans!!

We can only try a version which doesn't call processCommand, as we don't have all those other classes. That works as you want. What does your code do if you comment out the call to processCommand?

@tgdavies I've added to the question in bold at the bottom. I've noticed using System.out.println(); fixes the issue I'm having but i do not want the extra newline being printed. I've tried System.out.flush(); in hopes this would clear the print stream, but it doesnt seem to have any effect.. this issue doesnt so much have a big impact on the programs functionality, its just really annoying me!!  If using Eclipse it works as I want so I'm suspecting its the IDE that is the issue. Unless there are any other suggestions It may just be something out of my control as netbeans is required.
